# swfobject & flash -- display loading animation?

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I'm using swfobject to dynamically load a flash object into a div, and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to display a loading animation until the flash object is ready for display? In this case, I'm loading an embedded Issuu object, and you can see an example of Issuu loading via swfobject [**here**](http://issuu.com/services/api/viewer/example.html). Depending on your connection speed, there is typically just a blank white space while the flash object loads, and it'd be great to indicate progress with a loading animation if possible. I would imagine jQuery could be of service here...

Thanks for any direction here.

Comment: Put your Loading code on the first frame of the SWF. It should display before the full movie has loaded.

Comment: thanks jnpcl-- only thing is that I have not authored the SWF as it comes from Issuu; the objects can be manipulated via an API but I don't think I can actually insert a frame

Comment: hmm.. how about creating a container file with a loading animation, which loads & plays the actual SWF?

Answer (score 1):

In your embed code, you not only pass an id of the tag you want to be replaced by the swf (`idOfTagToReplace`), but also an id of the  tag replacing it (`issuuViewer`).
Right after your call to swfobject, style the latter tag as you like.

```
var attributes = {
    id: 'issuuViewer'
};

var params = {
    allowfullscreen: 'true',
    menu: 'false',
    wmode: 'transparent'
};

var flashvars = {
    jsAPIClientDomain: 'www.yourdomain.dk',
    mode: 'mini',
    documentId: '081219132433-764a1eafce5141fda136d10d58bd45f5'
};

swfobject.embedSWF(
    "http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v2/IssuuReader.swf", 
    "idOfTagToReplace", 
    "420", 
    "264", 
    "9.0.0",
    "swfobject/expressInstall.swf", 
    flashvars, 
    params, 
    attributes
);

var obj = document.getElementById('issuuViewer');
obj.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/img/loading.gif)';
obj.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
obj.style.backgroundPosition = '50% 50%';
```